# Re-use connection file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to keep open connection file separate and re-use on different places like in .cs files.
I dont want to rewrite code the following:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString()));
```

Is it possible in c#, like php include files include("opendb.php").

Comment: You are already doing that, aren't you? Web.config **IS** a separate file.

Comment: Read up on the Connection pool. The notation can be shortened with a simple method but mucking with the `using(){}` is unwise.

Comment: yes i am using Web.config, but i dont want re open connection code in cs file.

Comment: _"Is it possible in c#, like php include files include("opendb.php")"_ - please pick up a good book on object oriented design.

Comment: who down voted my question?

Comment: Whats wrong with this question?

Comment: Thanks, next time i will care.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't include anything - you just put the code into another class. For example:

```
public static class ConnectionHelper
{
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"]
                                                     .ToString())
    }
}
```

Then from your other code:

```
using (var conn = ConnectionHelper.GetConnection())
{
    ...
}
```

An alternative to consider - for greater testability - would be to use dependency injection. Make `GetConnection` an *instance* method, and potentially make `ConnectionHelper` implement an interface... then take that as a dependency (e.g. in your constructor). Ideally, few things should need the connection directly anyway - it would be better to expose more business-centric operations.

Comment: isn't static a bad approach in case of sqlconnection(just for thoughts)? and can you explain the interface theory a bit more

Comment: @Alok: It's a static *method* - it's not a static *field*. That's okay, but dependency injection would be cleaner. What side of that do you need more explanation for?

Comment: oh i thought the class was static too. Besides i didnt got how we can implement an interface

Comment: @Alok: The class *is* static (or was meant to be - will be in a second!) - but there's no field. The class would have to become non-static, as would the method, in order to implement the interface.

Comment: @AdnanKhan: Well did you add the `ConnectionHelper` class? If not, you *would* get that error...

Comment: @AdnanKhan: I provided the code in the answer. If you're sufficiently new that you don't understand how to add a class to your codebase, I think you should start from the beginning - don't try to run before you can walk.

Comment: @AdnanKhan: Stack Overflow isn't really suitable for this sort of thing. I'm not going to walk you through every mouse click of adding code - you should pick up a good book and learn from scratch. Trying to take short-cuts will just cost you time in the long run.